# Show direction between two markers in google map on clicking Navigation icon in flutter map view

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter

I want Google map to show direction between two markers(Marker 1 and Marker 2) on clicking Navigation icon on the bottom right. Currently google map loads with direction from current location to Marker 2 (marker currently clicked on) on clicking navigation icon.

I am using [`google_maps_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) dependency for showing map

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `url_launcher` which you might already using.

```
onPressed: () async{
  String googleUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=28.6207,77.3639&daddr=28.6057,77.3731';
  if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
     await launch(googleUrl);
  } else {
     throw 'Could not open the map.';
  }
},
```